# Swift Combine sink called once at setup?

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I am setting up a `sink` like so:

```
    name.publisher
        .removeDuplicates()
        .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
        .sink { [weak self] config in
            guard let self = self else { return }

            // this closure gets called right away at setup even though the @Published property `name` was already setup and did not change
            
        }.store(in: &subscribers)
```

The property is declared like so in an observable object:

```
 @Published var name:String = ""
```

So, I'm obviously missing something here. Why is sink called once at setup even though `name` did not change? I can avoid this behavior by using the `dropFirst()` operator but, I'd like to understand why the closure is always called once immediately after setup?

Why is that?

Comment: What is `name.publisher`? Is this an `@Published` variable?

Comment: From Scott answer it looks like compiler created CurrentValueSubject publisher with a default value,  and it always emits its default value downstream on subscription.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a playground that uses `debugPrint` to show you what you get from `name.publisher`:

```
import UIKit
import Combine

//Holds the score
class ViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var name = "0"
}

let viewModel = ViewModel()
debugPrint(viewModel.name.publisher)
```

What you get is

`Combine.Publishers.Sequence<Swift.String, Swift.Never>(sequence: "0")`

So you get a sequence publisher that has a single item, "0".  It will publish that value once and the sequence will end.  Each time a subscriber attaches to that sequence it will get all the items in the sequence (there's only one) and the end.

This is probably not what you want.

Instead I think you want to use `$name` to access the published property:

```
import UIKit
import Combine

//Holds the score
class ViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var name = "0"
}

let viewModel = ViewModel()
let subscription = viewModel.$name.sink { print($0) }
viewModel.name = "Alex"
```

When you subscribe to the published property *you will still get a posted event that is the current value of the property*.  However, by using `$name` you are attaching to a stream that will send you the current value on subscription AND each subsequent value.

Comment: You can avoid that first posted event by using `.dropFirst().sink { ... }` instead of just `.sink { ... }`.